# Why does querying contact picker require different permissions depending on the android version?

Tags: android, android-intent

We have been experimenting with the Android contact picker to allow users to select a contact without the app requiring the READ_CONTACTS permission.  The following intents appear to work on 4.0 (ICS) devices as well as a 2.3.3 emulator:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACION_GET_CONTENT);
contactPickerIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE); // returns content://com.android.contacts/data/...

Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI); // returns content://com.android.contacts/lookup/...
```

On a 2.2 emulator and certain pre-ICS models (e.g., HTC Thunderbolt, Motorola Droid), however, attempting to query the returned UI results in a permission denial exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
>   com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r1-52345052324E483C32/1 
>   from pid=273, uid=10036 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

This looks like a OS or device fragmentation issue; we're seeking clarification on this topic so that we can move forward with this or an alternate approach.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. At the bottom of [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) this behavior is documented:

> Before Android 2.3 (API level 9), performing a query on the Contacts Provider (like the one shown above) requires that your app declare the `READ_CONTACTS` permission (see Security and Permissions). However, beginning with Android 2.3, the Contacts/People app grants your app a temporary permission to read from the Contacts Provider when it returns you a result. The temporary permission applies only to the specific contact requested, so you cannot query a contact other than the one specified by the intent's `Uri`, unless you do declare the `READ_CONTACTS` permission.

There are a dozen other places where you would expect this to be documented, but that page is the only place I have found it explained.